# how to remove dots in php document which contains images

Tags: php, html

I would love to remove the Dots as you can see in the image Please Help
The Below is my code

```
 <body>
    <h1>Please Check Your Email For Verfication that you are not a Bot :-) </h1>
    <a href='hotmail.com' class="icon" ><img src="outlook.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>;
    <a href='gmail.com' class="icon"><img src="Gmail.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>;
    <a href='yahoo.com' class="icon"><img src="yahoo.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>;
    </body>`
```

[image]

Comment: Are these dots part of the image, or spurious text appearing in the web page?

Comment: the dots are not part of my image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps removing the semi-colons could help:

```
 <body>
    <h1>Please Check Your Email For Verfication that you are not a Bot :-) </h1>
    <a href='hotmail.com' class="icon" ><img src="outlook.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
    <a href='gmail.com' class="icon"><img src="Gmail.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
    <a href='yahoo.com' class="icon"><img src="yahoo.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
 </body>
```

Comment: Silly Me i was using Semi colons when i was in `HTML` tags,
thanks for noticing it 
i feel stupid :) ,
thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

No need for the semicolons at the end of your lines, see below:

```
<body>
  <h1>Please Check Your Email For Verfication that you are not a Bot :-)</h1>
  <a href='hotmail.com' class="icon" ><img src="outlook.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
  <a href='gmail.com' class="icon"><img src="Gmail.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
  <a href='yahoo.com' class="icon"><img src="yahoo.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
</body>
```

If you'd like to review HTML syntax, this site is a great resource: [HTML5 Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few issues that are causing extra symbols to appear, and the links won't work as you'd expect.

The semi-colons are showing up because you have semi-colons after each `<br/>` which don't need to be there.

The underscores after each image are appearing because the images are nested in anchor tags. Anchor tags by default have an underline text decoration, and images have a small bit of extra sizing in most cases.

In anchor tags on almost all webservers, if you don't define a protocol (like `http://`) to use, then it will send the user to `http://yoursite.com/<current_page>/<clicked_link>` rather than the external website that you'd expect.

Using these should fix all of that:

### HTML

```
 <body>
    <h1>Please Check Your Email For Verfication that you are not a Bot :-) </h1>
    <a href="http://hotmail.com" class="icon" ><img src="outlook.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
    <a href="http://gmail.com" class="icon"><img src="Gmail.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com" class="icon"><img src="yahoo.png" width="70px" height="70px"/></a><br>
 </body>
```

### CSS

```
.icon {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```